# Question on Rudin's proof of Theorem 9.5 in Real and Complex Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I'm working through Theorem 9.5 in Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis and I'm having trouble understanding one of the steps.  The statement of the proof is as follows:
[image]

Rudin uses Theorem 3.14, which states that $C_C(X)$ is dense in $L^p(X)$, to obtain the function $g$ and this is where my confusion comes in. I don't understand how Rudin deduces the uniform continuity of $g$ rather than just continuity.  My understanding is that $C_C(X)$ includes all continuous complex functions with compact support and not just uniformly continuous functions.  Any help understanding this would be appreciated.

Comment: Since the support of $g$ is compact, it is uniformly continuous on its support (since continuous functions on compact sets are uniformly continuous). Outside its support it is zero, so it is uniformly continuous there. You can then use the overall continuity to deal with the boundary of the support and conclude that it is uniformly continuous on $X$.

Comment: Thanks!  That makes a lot more sense now.